# Unable to create UserAgentApplication with Microsoft Authentication library in a node project

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to create a **UserAgentApplication** in my node project with **@azure/msal-node** library but i am getting an error *TypeError: Msal.UserAgentApplication is not a constructor*. The below is my detailed code and error response.

```
    const Msal = require("@azure/msal-node");

    const config = {
    auth: {
      clientId: "xxx-xxxx-xxxx",
      authority:"https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx-xxxxx",
      validateAuthority: true,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://localhost:3000",
      redirectUri: "https://localhost:3000/app",
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
    },
  };

  const maslAuthorize = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(config);

  module.exports = maslAuthorize;
```

**Error Response:**

const maslAuthorize = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(config);
TypeError: Msal.UserAgentApplication is not a constructor

Comment: You can't use `UserAgentApplication` on `@azure/msal-node` consider using `PublicClientApplication`

Comment: how's going? has your issue been solved?

Answer (score 0):

As @fortunee indicated, `UserAgentApplication` is not for `@azure/msal-node`, you should use `ConfidentialClientApplication` or `PublicClientApplication` to login users.

You can find all `@azure/msal-node` OAuth 2.0 flow sample code [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-node#samples).